# How do I use a for loop here?

Tags: python, for-loop

Instead of creating more grade variables, is there a way I could use a for loop to create these variables and then input them into the def_calc functions? I'm not allowed to use lists for this assignment and I'm curious if there is a way to make my code look prettier and faster.

Also, sorry if the code is bad, I'm really new to python.

```
def main():
  grade1 = int(input('Enter a grade: '))
  grade2 = int(input('Enter another grade: '))
  grade3 = int(input('Enter even another grade: '))
  grade4 = int(input('Enter another another grade: '))
  grade5 = int(input('Enter one last grade: '))
  calc_average(grade1 , grade2 , grade3 , grade4 , grade5)
  print('your average test grade is' , average)
def calc_average(grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,grade5):
  global average
  average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5) / 5
  return average
main()
```

Comment: Do you have ideas on where to start? Can you include any initial ideas in your question?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use a loop here without using lists(or any other collection)

Comment: @SuperStormer it's definitely possible. But only if the grades don't need to be saved individually. If the only thing OP needs to do is average the grades, then they can just accumulate all the grade values.

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use lists for this assignment and I'm curious if there is a way to make my code look prettier and faster." The correct way is to use *some sort of container* like a `list` or `dict`, do **not** dynamically create variables. That is a bad practice, and indeed it is not possible inside functions in CPython. If you aren't allowed to use lists, just do it like this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you so much for your feedback. I always try to dynamically create variables and if it's bad practice I'm gonna try and get out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this if you don't need to use the `calc_average` function:

```
def main():
    total = 0
    for i in range(5):
        total += int(input('Enter a grade: '))
    
    print('your average test grade is' , total / 5)
```

Comment: `sum` is a built-in function in Python, and you're overwriting it.

Comment: This is very simplistic and has informed me of a new operator!  thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this using a `for` loop. You could write a `get_grades` function with a parameter for how many grades the user should input:

```py
def get_grades(num_grades):
    pass
```

Then use a `for` loop `num_grades` number of times to to add a new grade to a running total (if you're not planning to use the grades for anything other than checking the average). Here's some pseudocode:

1. Initialize a `grades_total`
2. Ask the user to input a grade
3. Add that grade to the `grades_total`
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 `num_grades` number of times
5. Divide `grades_total` by `num_grades`

If you DO need to use the grades for any other calculations, then this isn't possible without using some collection like a `list` or `tuple`.

Comment: To clarify, if you are asking if it's possible to dynamically create variables in Python then the answer is no, and even if you could that'd be a bad idea.

Comment: this makes sense. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @sosimplesoez you're very welcome. Don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

your can also use `while loop` to add more grades:

```py
import numpy as np
def main():
    n = 0
    grade_list = []
    while True:
        n = n + 1
        grade_str = input(f'Enter grade {n}, or Enter `c` to stop: ')
        if grade_str == 'c':
            if len(grade_list) > 0:
                average = np.mean(grade_list)
                print('your average test grade is' , average)
            break
        grade_list.append(int(grade_str))
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to not repeat something over and over again manually. So, in your code, instead of getting input 5 times, you can make it as a for loop:

```
def grade_average(n_grade = 5):

    sum_of_grades = 0
    for i in range(n_grade):
        grade = int(input('Enter a grade({} out of {}):'.format(i+1,n_grade)))
        sum_of_grades += grade

    average_grade = sum_of_grades / n_grade
    print('your average test grade is' , average_grade)


grade_average()
```

You can also get rid of some lines by not showing each step and make it shorter. For instance, look at the response provided by @epsilonmajorquezero.

Comment: I really like the way you did this because of the string formatting. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that adds some input validation:

```py
def get_number_input(prompt):
    num = -1
    while True:
        try:
            num = float(input(prompt))
            break
        except:
            print('Error: Enter a number, try again...')
    return num


def main():
    number_of_grades = 5
    total = 0
    for g in range(1, number_of_grades + 1):
        total += get_number_input(f'Please enter grade {g} of {number_of_grades}: ')
    average_grade = total / number_of_grades
    print(f'The average of the {number_of_grades} grades you entered is: {average_grade:.2f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter grade 1 of 5: 45
Please enter grade 2 of 5: a
Error: Enter a number, try again...
Please enter grade 2 of 5: 98
Please enter grade 3 of 5: 58
Please enter grade 4 of 5: 78.40
Please enter grade 5 of 5: 96.89
The average of the 5 grades you entered is: 75.26
```

Comment: OP states that they cannot use lists.